# Memory and data assembly

Tags: memory, assembly

I can't figure out how data are handled in different situations in assembly tables.

I have the following simple program:

```
section .data
        Digits:  db "0123456789ABCDEF"
        Sums:    dd 15,12,6,0,21,14,4,0,0,19
        Sums2:   db 15,12,6,0,21,14,4,0,0,19

section .text   
global _start


_start:
    nop                    ; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    mov ecx,2
    mov al, byte [Sums+ecx*2]
    mov bl, byte [Sums2+ecx*2]
    mov dl, byte [Digits+ecx*2]
    nop
```

Now, when I debug it instruction by instruction I look at the registers and can't understand what is happening.

```
rcx --> as expected it contains the decimal 2
rdx --> as expected it contains the hexadecimal 34 which represents the decimal 4
rax --> has c which represents new page
rbx --> has 15 which represents negative acknowledge (NAK character)
```

I expected finding 6 in rax and 1 in rbx. I can't figure out why it is not happening. I'm on a little endian architecture. Thanks

Comment: Your `Sums` and `Sums2` are defined as decimal values, but your debugger is displaying *hex* values. `0xC` == `12`, `0x15` == `21`. `Sums` is an array of `DWORD`s, so each element takes up 4 bytes - you are seeing the lowest byte of the second element. `Sums2` is an array of bytes, so you are seeing the fifth element.

Comment: Why are you expecting 1 in rbx? There is no 1 in sight anywhere..

Comment: Imaging an addressing line starting from 0 in al I'm reading bits 32-40 in the double word 32-64 (the second element). As I'm on a little endian arch. shouldn't the number be in bits 58-64? The rest is clear, I wrongly thought that each number took up one byte and I didn't consider that Digits is a string and the conversion happens while for numbers obviously it doesn't happen. Thanks